# Updating multiple fields for an Object - Dynamics CRM 2011 using java

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Is there any way to update multiple fields for an object in Dynamics CRM 2011 using java. All I am able to do now is to update one field for an object (ContactSet,AccountSet etc..)

URL : https://xxxxxx.xxxx.xx/xxxxxx/XrmServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet(guid'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')

What I have done?

```
    Map<String,Object> update = Maps.newHashMap();
    update.put("FirstName","xxxxx");
    update.put("LastName","xxxxx");
    update.put("Telephone1","xxxxxxxx");


    ObjectMapper mMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mEntity = mMapper.writeValueAsString(update);

    String mUrl = this.url+"/"+getObject()+"(guid'"+id+"')";

    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(mUrl);
    httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPut.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    httpPut.setEntity(new StringEntity(mEntity,"UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response = this.client.execute(httpPut);
```

The above code always gives a 500 internal server error. 
What works?

```
    Map<String,Object> update = Maps.newHashMap();
    update.put("FirstName","xxxxx");
    mEntity = mMapper.writeValueAsString(update);

    String mUrl = this.url+"/"+getObject()+"(guid'"+id+"')"+"/FirstName";
    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(mUrl);
    httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPut.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    httpPut.setEntity(new StringEntity(mEntity,"UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response = this.client.execute(httpPut);
```

I don't see a point in updating just a single field. Can someone please give pointers on how to update multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [javascript and Jquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx) or if you prefer java try to follow the microsoft code [Javascript example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387.aspx).

It is possible to update multiple columns, just check your code syntax.

Comment: Using HttpPost and this line - req.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE"); worked for me.